# Is it inversion for relative clause after ''verb''?

Tags: word-order, inversion

> Near the beginning of the story, something happens **that starts the action rolling.**

I found the writer put "relative clause after verb'' to avoid long subject. What I want to know is ''Is this writing called "Inversion" or other usage?''

Answer (score 1):

There is no inversion here.

This is simply called "extraposed relative clause" or "relative clause in extraposition," that is to say, one that is separated from its antecedent (*something*) by the main verb, in this case.